# Check ismember within a cell

Tags: matlab, compare, cell

I have a cell array (`data`) that looks like this (shortened here):

```
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733144  NaN
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733147  NaN
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733150  NaN
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733153  NaN
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733156  NaN
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733159  NaN
```

I want to fill in the 5th column of `NaN`'s depending on whether the 4th column (which are dates that has been converted using `datenum`) matches `B`.

`B` (also a cell) looks like this (also shortened a lot for the example to make sense):

```
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733144  '3.3'
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733150  '9.5'
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733156  '6.8'
```

As you can see, the 4th column of dates do not advance consistently in `B`. I'm trying to add in `NaN`'s to column 5 where `B(:,3)` and `B(:, 4)` do not match `data(:,3)` and `data(:, 4)`.

The end product should look something like:

```
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733144  '3.3'
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733147  NaN
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733150  '9.5'
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733153  NaN
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733156  '6.8'
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733159  NaN
```

If `data` was a matrix, I would just do the following:

```
data_ind = ismember(data(:,3:4),B(:,3:4),'rows');
```

But I don't know how to do it with a cell. Would some form of `cellfun` do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what you're doing with the third column as all of the entries are identical. Also, your question is a bit confusing as to if you want `B` in `data` or `data` in `B`. Probably the fastest and most straightforward way to do this is with a `for` loop:

```
data = {'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733144  NaN
        '45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733147  NaN
        '45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733150  NaN
        '45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733153  NaN
        '45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733156  NaN
        '45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733159  NaN};

B = {'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733144  '3.3'
     '45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733150  '9.5'
     '45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733156  '6.8'};

d3 = data(:,3);
d4 = [data{:,4}].';
for i = 1:size(B,1)
    data(strcmp(d3,B{i,3})&d4==B{i,4},5) = B(i,5);
end
```

Don't be afraid to use `for` loops. You can do it with `cellfun` too, but it will require the use of `eval`.

Comment: Plus one for readability. Although I admire the tricks needed to avoid loops, that doesn't mean for loops are not the best solution sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

```
sd = size(data,1); %// number of rows of data
sb = size(B,1); %// number of rows of B
[dd bb] = ndgrid(1:sd,1:sb); %// all combinations (row of data, row of B)
cond1 = strcmp(data(dd,3),B(bb,3)); %// test col 3 for all combinations
cond2 = [data{dd,4}].'==[B{bb,4}].'; %// test col 4 for all combinations
cond = reshape(cond1 & cond2, sd, sb); %// combine the two conditions
[ib, id] = max(cond); %// id contains the index of the first 1 (if any) ...
%// ... of each col in cond; and ib is a logical index of the row of that 1
id = id(ib); %// keep only id for which the maximum is 1
data(id,:) = B(ib,:); %// copy matching rows of B into data
```

Example where both `data` and `B` contain rows that don't match any row of the other variable:

```
data = {
    '45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733144  NaN
    '45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733147  NaN
    '45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733150  NaN
    '45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733153  NaN
    '45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733156  NaN
    '45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733159  NaN};

B = {
    '45.203885'    '-90.600123'    '119-8001'    [733144]    '3.3'
    '45.203885'    '-90.600123'    '119-8001'    [733150]    '9.5'
    '45.203885'    '-90.600123'    '119-8001'    [733156]    '6.8'
    '45.203885'    '-90.600123'    '169-8001'    [833156]    '6.8'};
```

Result:

```
data = 

    '45.203885'    '-90.600123'    '119-8001'    [733144]    '3.3'
    '45.203885'    '-90.600123'    '119-8001'    [733147]    [NaN]
    '45.203885'    '-90.600123'    '119-8001'    [733150]    '9.5'
    '45.203885'    '-90.600123'    '119-8001'    [733153]    [NaN]
    '45.203885'    '-90.600123'    '119-8001'    [733156]    '6.8'
    '45.203885'    '-90.600123'    '119-8001'    [733159]    [NaN]
```

Comment: It says the `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.` for the last line. `data(data_ind,:) is size 252x5. B is size 190x5 since it has missing dates.

Comment: @shizishan I've rewritten my answer with a new approach. I think now it works in the general case

Comment: The `strcmp(C1,C2)` syntax + `ndgrid` is just the ticket here. No need for `ismember` or a `for` loop. Clever.

Comment: @chappjc Thanks! It's funny how in this case the two outputs of `max` give the two needed indices (column index in logical form, row index in number form)

Comment: @chappjc: Yes, but what about readability? (Who knows about speed.) And `ndgrid` is as much of a `for` loop as `arrayfun` or `cellfun` while using more memory. And @LuisMendo: was this question deleted for a while or something? It wasn't there when both @MrAzzaman and I posted ours, yet the time stamp is much older for some reason.

Comment: @horchler Excellent point. Re: time stamps, see [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21412708/revisions). I do this occasionally if I realize I answered too quickly and don't want to gather downvotes. :) It happens!

Comment: @LuisMendo How does the `id = id(val)` line work? MATLAB just says `val` is undefined.

Comment: @horchler Yes, I deleted it because I realized the answer was wrong. The I rewrote it. Perhaps I should have posted a new answer and have kept the old one deleted?

Comment: @shizishan Sorry, `val` should be `ib`. Corrected. Please try it now

Answer (score 2):

Since you will only ever have unique ID+datenum combinations, you could do something like the following:

```
data_ind = ismember(strcat(data(:,3),num2str([data{:,4}]')),...
                    strcat(B(:,3),num2str([B{:,4}]')));
```

What this does is concatenate the 3rd and 4th columns into a single string, e.g.

```
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733144  NaN
'45.203885' '-90.600123'    '119-8001'  733147  NaN
```

would become

```
'119-8001733144'
'119-8001733147'
```

and so on. It then compares these strings from the `data` matrix to the `B` matrix to give you an index matrix.

Comment: Nice. If column four is always an integer, `int2str` would probably be better. And if those values are ever decimal, note that by default `num2str` only uses "about 4 digits and an exponent if required" (`sprintf('%.17g',...)` is safer).

Comment: Column 4 is a datenum type number, and will always be an integer as no hour/min/sec data is provided. Good point about `int2str`, however it shouldn't make much difference - `num2str` falls back to `int2str` if the input is an integer. Yes, there is a little overhead in checking that the number is an integer, but this is negligible in the long run.